# Application that will install application

Tags: software-rec, installer

I'm thinking of a software that comes with pc decrapifier. Which can do the exact opposite of what pc decrapifier can do. 
Install a number of applications in one click.
Is there an application like that?Not a web app please, I already know of that but I forgot the name, so if you know that please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OpenDisc is a high quality collection
>   of open source software (OSS) for the
>   Microsoft Windows operating system.

http://www.theopendisc.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple... but I was never very happy with the ones I tried.  Sorry can't remember the names.

However, if the applications have silent installers, just make your own batch file and set your own switches.